# Comparing columns occasionally throws false positives

Tags: ssis

I'm working on an SSIS package, adding update functionality (updating rows by using a staging table). To do this, I use a lookup and conditional split where I compare all the columns.

[image]

For some reason, some of the data throws false positives and marks rows as changed, when they have not. I've isolated this down to a single string column (zip code).

The column comes straight from a lookup. The source data column is `varchar(9)`, the destination (i.e. source of second value) is `char(9)`. In SSIS, both columns come through as `DT_STR,9,1252`

[image]

If I start with an empty table, and run the package twice, the second time about 20% of the rows come up as changed, even though they haven't. The following sql joins the existing rows to the "updated" rows in the staging table and compares their zips:

```
SELECT a.key_DestinationZip, b.key_DestinationZip,
CASE WHEN a.key_DestinationZip = b.key_DestinationZip then 1 else 0 end
FROM [dbo].[sta_Sales] as a
join [dbo].[fact_Sales] as b
on a.key_FullSalesNumber = b.key_FullSalesNumber
```

with results similar to

```
78735       78735       1
38138       38138       1
```

Comment: My initial guess is that your char/varchar difference and the default ansi_padding settings. If you applied an RTRIM to both the source and lookup Zips, does the problem persist?

Comment: @billinkc That did it, add an answer and I'll accept. So what's actually happening under the hood? I assumed that when the varchar column got pulled in by SSIS, it got padded to whatever length the DT_STR is. I guess that's not the case? I assumed that `abc` and `abc   ` (3 spaces) would be the same if the destination datatype is DT_STR with length 6 - now it seems like the non-padded one would actually not be length 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source data is varchar(9) and your lookup data is char(9). I believe, but have not tested, this is resulting in `|65401|` and `|65401    |` (4 spaces there and pipes for delineation only) in your data.

The data coming from your source system is going to be affected by the `ANSI_PADDING` setting when it was loaded. By default, SSIS isn't going to pad out the string.

Therefore, in your lookup, you will want to either pad the source data to 9 characters or trim the lookup's key.

And unrelated to this, but you might want to store the postal code separate from the zip+4 data. The later is more likely to change than the former when/if you ever run your data through an address validation service.

Answer (score 0):

That looks to me like the problem is your data has two zip codes.

Comment: I'm comparing the new zip code to the old zip code, but it hasn't changed (e.g. if I run it twice, about 20% of the rows are "updated", same rows each time)

Comment: That is because the address is in there twice with two differnt zip codes.